# Expired authorization code in PHP facebook SDK

Tags: php, facebook

I am using the new 4.* facebook php SDK and I am having an issue! ;)

Basically I am trying to find a way to make requests to the graph api after the first redirect when the user is **sent back to my site after logging in into facebook**. In that case I do (in my `index.php`):

```
$h = FacebookRedirectLoginHelper("blablabla");
$request = new FacebookRequest($h->getSessionFromRedirect(), 'GET', '/me');
$me = $request->execute()->getGraphObject();
```

and it works perfectly and I can print the date about the logged user.

My problem is that if I reload (f5) the page `index.php` then I get an exception:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException' with message 'This authorization code has expired.' in /home/nourdine/development/faisbuk/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php:87
```

So my question is: where am I supposed to get a new authorization code in order to make new graph api calls with the authenticated user even in pages that are not executed as a result o the facebook login process?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a new authorization code. What you need is to use the same session. `$h->getSessionFromRedirect()` returns a session. That session you want to use next time also.

Comment: So is it my responsibility to store it somewhere and check at every page load if it is available?

Comment: Yes. Use `FacebookSession->getToken()` to get the token and you can put that in $_SESSION for example. Then you just check for `$_SESSION['token']` and if it is set use `$session = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['token']);`

Answer (score 1):

Concretely speaking, this piece of code is what needs to be implemented:

```
    // see if we have a session in $_Session[]
if( isset($_SESSION['token']))
{
    // We have a token, is it valid? 
    $session = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['token']); 
    try
    {
        $session->Validate($appid ,$secret);
    }
    catch( FacebookAuthorizationException $ex)
    {
        // Session is not valid any more, get a new one.
        $session ='';
    }
}
```

Full working sample is available at this page: [Facebook SDK 4.0.0 for PHP: A working sample to manage sessions](http://metah.ch/blog/2014/05/facebook-sdk-4-0-0-for-php-a-working-sample-to-manage-sessions/).

Comment: Please don't do this, you're essentially making a network requests to Facebook's api on each and every page load - there's no need for this.
Just handle exceptions when using the API's instead.