# JS and PHP SDK 4.0 best practice for authorization - $_SESSION?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to implement login and registration on a page using the Facebook API for both JS and PHP SDK 4.0. The 4.0 SDK seems relatively new and have changed a lot in recent time. There aren't a lot of answers out there. The documentation also seems pretty poor.

I already have a page with standard login using php/mysql. This will just be another option of login/registration for users.

After a couple of years just reading on Stackoverflow, this is my first post. Sorry in advance if it's in some way inadequate.

This is how I figure I would like to set this up:

- A Facebook-button next to the login with a JS Facebook-login dialog connected to it.
- If the user authorizes: send the result with an ajax-request to a php-page
- Use FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper to set up a session.
- Get a long life access-token with getLongLivedSession.
- Make a request for /me. Check if the email for this account is already a user on my site.
- If not already a user: Ask for a username, register the user with info from Facebook.
- Connect the account by saving the internal userid and the access-token in my database

Questions so far:

- Am I supposed to send the token with my AJAX-call from the client, or would this be a security risk? I could just fetch the token with the PHP SDK instead.
- Should i store the token with $_SESSION? Should I even store this manually myself? If so, is there built in functionality for this in the PHP SDK? Couldn't find any.

When a user has gone through this process I want to be able to check server side directly on page load if the user has authorized my app (and is logged in on FB).

- Am I supposed to acquire the access-token using $_SESSION, or is there functionality for this? Isn't there any built in functionality to do a standard check if the user is authorized already?
- When doing this in PHP, should I use the FacebookRedirectLoginHelper? Seems a bit odd since I'd never want to redirect with PHP, when my login dialogs will be with JS.

Maybe I've gotten the gist of this all wrong. My main concern is if I really would have to be storing the token with $_SESSION. I've seen a lot of people doing it in tutorials, but found nothing about it in Facebooks docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your detailed post. Not a lot of people put so much effort in their first post ;)

The token you refer to is automatically stored in the cookie by the JS SDK. You can instantiate a session on the PHP side in the following way:

```
$js_helper = new FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper($app_id);
$session = $js_helper->getSession();
```

Or: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper/4.0.0

You don't have to store the token by yourself, since it's already stored in the cookie.

Does this make the situation more clear?

Comment: This will give me a "Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException: This authorization code has expired". If i dump the cookie the stored token isn't the same as the long lived token I get from getLongLivedSession. Do I have to replace the cookie with my new token instead?

Comment: Please use Google when you get clear Exception codes. First hit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584021/expired-authorization-code-in-php-facebook-sdk

Comment: That answer regards using the FacebookRedirectLoginHelper, not the FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper as described in your answer. If i use that instead I get null as a result. So, getSession will work in my first ajax-call when the user logs in to facebook. How will i then on a page reload be able to get the users session again?

Comment: This is actually not quite correct, the code stored in the cookie is only valid for a single use, and must be exchanged for what the PHP sdk calls a session - basically the access token. This session should then be stored in $_SESSION and reused for future api calls. If you have a long lived token, then this can also be stored, and a session can be created around it.